# Only one instance of a messaging application receiving messages

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In the code below I have 3 functions (including `main`). The `receive_loop` function polls the socket bound to `127.0.0.1` and if it gets any message, it prints it. The `sender_loop` waits for user input using `scanf` and when there is an input, it sends it through the socket bound to `127.0.0.1`. The `main` forks and runs `sender_loop` in child and `receive_loop` in the parent.

Now if I compile the code and run two instances of this executable, whichever instance starts up first receives the messages sent by either instance. So lets say, instance1 was started first, then instance1 receives messages sent by instance1 AND instance2. I cannot figure out why this is happening and I would appreciate if someone could explain it please (in detail). Thanks.

```
// INCLUDES NOT SHOWN

// recieve_loop
int receive_loop(int sock_fd, struct sockaddr *peer) {
    int isDataReady = 0;
    char buff[128]  = {0};
    struct pollfd poll_struct;

    poll_struct.fd     = sock_fd; 
    poll_struct.events = POLLIN;

    printf("reciever up\n");
    while (1) {
        while (1) {
            if (isDataReady > 0) break;
            isDataReady = poll(&poll_struct, 1, 500);
        }
        socklen_t sock_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        recvfrom(sock_fd,
                buff,
                sizeof(buff),
                0,
                (struct sockaddr *)peer,
                &sock_len);

        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }

    return 0;
}


// sender_loop
int sender_loop(int sock_fd, struct sockaddr *peer) {
    char buff[32] = {0};

    printf("sender up\n");
    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", buff);

        int bytes_sent = sendto(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        if (bytes_sent <= 0)
            printf("sending message failed\n");

    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // socket file descriptor to send data through
    int sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    // fill in the peer's address, loopback in this case
    struct sockaddr_in *peer = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    peer->sin_family = AF_INET;
    peer->sin_port   = htons(11110);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &peer->sin_addr);

    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't fork, exiting");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        sender_loop(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)peer);
    } else {
        receive_loop(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)peer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second instance is failing on `bind()` because it is trying to bind to a port already in use by the first instance.

Change to this and see.

```
int ret = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: But why is the second instance still able to send the messages? It shouldn't be able to either receive OR send the messages right?

Comment: Prior to calling bind, you can also use the SO_REUSEADDR setting with setsocktopt to avoid the bind failing.  Both instances of your program will run.  When an incoming packet comes in, one of the instances will handle the packet. For SOCK_DGRAM (UDP) you are definitely NOT guaranteed that packets sent from a particular host will be processed by the same program instance.

Comment: @mtahmed - UDP sockets are still allowed to "send" if they haven't been binded to a particular port.  OS will choose a random unused value as the source port.

Comment: As a matter of fact, since you are using the same port for send and receive, your own design may cause the sending program to receive the messages he sent.  A standard design for this would be to let the client pick a random port number (i.e. set 0 for port number before calling bind) and then inform a server listening on a well known IP:port about the presence of such a user.  Have you considered just having a local "server" process that all clients connect to, and then it redirects messages to the appropriate destination?

Comment: @selbie Thanks a lot man for the detailed answers and suggestions. I was actually trying to go towards making it so that I can talk to other people on the same network using a peer-to-peer sort of connection. But i guess at some point, some sort of a server would be required. And yes, I did realize that it was stupid to use the same port and ip to send a receive messages. Thanks a lot again. I appreciate it.